# Creating mailboxes on Exchange 2010

Tags: c#, vb.net, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I have a project on VS 2005 which was running fine with exchange 2003, now the customer migrated to 2010 and my app. is failing when tries to create mailbox.

My app. is console based and its running on windows 2003 and 2.0 .net framework. Exchange 2010 is running on a W2K8 and 3.5 framework.

I guess a good option would be to develop a webservice (with VS 2010 for example) but not sure if EWS is able create mailboxes.

I'd like to hear some advices on this matter.

Thanks in advance,
m0dest0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use EWS to create mailboxes. For that you should use powershell. You can run powershell scripts from your C# app, see this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

So in your case I would Exchange Management Shell on the application server and write an application that creates mailboxes using powershell/EMS.

Comment: the example on codeproject is running locally which is pretty easy however, as far as I know, run remote powershell using C# is not so easy. I'd prefer to use a kind of web service, for example, using *proxy web service* makes sense to you?

Comment: So you would like to make a web service running on the Exchange server and then call the web service from a remote machine to create the mailboxes?
I don't think there's a web service you can use for that purpose - you would need to implement your own (which should be pretty easy by using powershell locally on the Exchange server).

Comment: I'm checking this as an answer because I'm following your suggestion, I mean, I'm developing a WCF wich is gonna be hosted on the Exchange Server and it's going to run a PS command there. Thanks